# css hover image - staying put

Tags: css, image

I have the below two images one is a roll over image which displays another image

```css
/* HOVER IMG */
.hover_img a { position:static; }
.hover_img a span { position:fixed; display:none; z-index:99;}
.hover_img a:hover span { display:block; position: fixed; top: 5px; width:800px; margin-left:140px;}
```

```html
  <div class="hover_img">
  <a href="link.html"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" style="border : 0;" width="120" height="30"/><span><img style="border: 5px solid #000000;border-radius: 25px; width:800px" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/></span></a>
  </div>
```

the problem i have is that when moving off the original image, and moving to the roll over if you move fast enough when the mouse is over the roll over image it then stays and doesnt remove.

As the roll over image is quite large i am looking for a way in which if the mouse is over the roll over image then it doesnt show?

Answer (score 0):

I got the hover image to disappear by messing around with the positioning of span image.

```
.hover_img 
a:hover span {   
  display:block; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0%; 
  left: -100px;
  width:800px; 
  margin-left:140px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/edubz/pen/jeBPKe

Comment: The image does disappear on my side if you mouse out of the actual image but on my version because they are close to each other if you move quick enough and go over the roll over image it then doesnt go away. So i am trying to find a solution that when the original image is hovered it shows the image, but the when you go outside of this it the hides the roll over image

Answer (score 0):

use `padding-left` instead of margin for 20px  and also use `left:120px` to position your `span` element.

```css
/* HOVER IMG */
.hover_img a { position:static; }
.hover_img a span { position:fixed; display:none; z-index:99;}
.hover_img a:hover span { display:block; position: fixed; top: 5px; left:120px width:800px; padding-left:20px;}
```

```html
  <div class="hover_img">
  <a href="link.html"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" style="border : 0;" width="120" height="30"/><span><img style="border: 5px solid #000000;border-radius: 25px; width:800px" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/></span></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as when you mouse out of the original image over the roll over image, the roll over image is still there. I need something when you mouse out of the static image, even if you are over the roll over image, the rollover image disappears

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

onmouseout="document.getElementById('over6').style.visibility = 'hidden';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('over6').style.visibility = 'visible';"

and giving my span the id as above, it meant as soon as you mouse in and out it will show and hide the image, this solve the issues of the over image still showing when you mouse over it.